# How to resolve "'jpackage' is missing" error when creating a distributable build for desktop in Compose Multiplatform using Android Studio?

Tags: build-error, jpackage, compose-multiplatform

I'm currently working on a Compose Multiplatform project using Kotlin and targeting desktop platforms. I'm encountering an issue when trying to create a distributable build for desktop in Android Studio, specifically with the error message:
"Failed to check jdk distribution: 'jpackage' is missing."

This error seems to be related to the absence of the 'jpackage' tool, which is used for creating self-contained application packages in Java. I'm unsure about how to resolve this issue and proceed with creating a distributable build for desktop platforms.

If anyone has experience with creating distributable builds for desktop platforms in Compose Multiplatform projects using Android Studio, I would greatly appreciate any insights, recommendations, or step-by-step instructions to resolve this issue.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: java version 17

Comment: Please read tag descriptors before using the tag. `Distribution` is reserved for issues relating to statistical distributions.